# How to construct this url using retrofit library?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

how can i contruct this URL `avmlabs.in/avm_db/check_login.php?x={"email":"user@gmail.com"}`  using retrofit library. I don't know how to do. i'm new in retrofit library.

this is API interface I have created

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @POST("check_login.php")
    Call<Login> checkEmail(@Field("x") String email);


}
```

this one model class

```
public class Login {

    public String status_code,status_message,success;

    public String getStatus_code() {
        return status_code;
    }

    public void setStatus_code(String status_code) {
        this.status_code = status_code;
    }

    public String getStatus_message() {
        return status_message;
    }

    public void setStatus_message(String status_message) {
        this.status_message = status_message;
    }

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }
}
```

but i got `avmlabs.in/avm_db/check_login.php?x=user@gmail.com`  this response.

Comment: You mean to say you want `x={"email:user@gmail.com"} ` while you get `x=user@gmail.com`?

Comment: yeah i want x = {"email":"user@gmail.com"} this one

Comment: why do you need { } why not change on the server side and have email=user@gmail.com would make it simpler

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Using Gson

Create a class

```
public class RequestJson {
     String email;
     public RequestJson(String email){
          this.email = email;
     }
}

RequestJson requestJson = new RequestJson("user@gmail.com");
```

Change ApiInterface to

```
@POST("check_login.php")
Call<Login> checkEmail(@Field("x") RequestJson requestJson);
```

call directly with the object.

Method 2: Using JSONObject

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("email", "user@gmail.com");
String email = jsonObject.toString();
```

Pass this string to Retrofit. You will get {"email":"user@gmail.com"} as request

Comment: I am using 2nd method.i got this url  http://avmlabs.in/avm_db/check_login.php?x={%22email%22:%22user@gmail.com%22}.how to encoded?

Comment: @priyadharsini if you want json then why not send the same in the body instead as query params. or just have `email=user@gmail.com` which is simpler

Comment: @Raghunandan but that is also not working.here is my code JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("email", "user@gmail.com");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String email = jsonObject.toString();
            Log.e("email", String.valueOf(jsonObject));
            Call<Login> call = apiInterface.checkEmail(jsonObject);

Comment: Use the first method and change to Call<Login> checkEmail(@Field("x") RequestJson requestJson);. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Refer https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845

If the value is already encoded, you can disable URL encoding like this: @Path(value="name", encoded=true)

Comment: Great...Thanks Got a output@SushinPS and @Raghunandan